# CRUD Operations on Datatables for multiple model using jquery MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I try to run my CRUD application for multiple model of Admin information on datatables using JavaScript MVC.

I am surfing net , read many the forum and also follow step from youtuber but i m
hang for this two function "Add" and "Edit" on few weeks.

Please help me to check and solve which coding part i'm wrong.

**What I have tried:**

1. "Add New" function cannot back to same screen when pressed "Submit" button.
2. "Edit" function cannot display out information when pressed "Edit" as pencil icon button
3. "GetAdminData" function can show records on screen .

Here my coding part on below:

In Models part:

```
public partial class ADMIN
  {
      public string ADMIN_ID { get; set; }
      public string ADMIN_NAME { get; set; }
      public string ADMIN_PASSWORD { get; set; }
      public string ADMIN_EMAIL { get; set; }
      public string ADMIN_STATUS { get; set; }
      public string ADMIN_COMMENT { get; set; }
     public virtual STATUS STATUS { get; set; }
  }
  
 public partial class STATUS
  {   public string STATUS_ID { get; set; }
      public string STATUS_DESC { get; set; }
  }
```

In main View part:

```
@model IEnumerable<ABC.Models.ADMIN>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin Profile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage2.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("StoreOrEdit","Admin")')">class="fa fa-plus">Add New</a>


<table id="adminTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("ID")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Password")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Email")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Status")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Comment")
            </th>
            <th></th>
           
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<pre>@section scripts{
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
   
    <script>

        var Popup, dataTable;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable = $("#adminTable").DataTable({

                "ajax": {

                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetAdminData", "Admin")",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "ADMIN_ID" },
                    { "data": "ADMIN_NAME" ,"width":"100px"},
                     { "data": "ADMIN_PASSWORD" },
                       { "data": "ADMIN_EMAIL" },
                         { "data": "STATUS_DESC" },
                           { "data": "ADMIN_COMMENT" },
                    {
                        "data": "ADMIN_ID", "render": function (data) {

                            return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("StoreOrEdit","Admin")/" + data + "')>">Edit</a>" +
                                   " <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")>">Delete</a>";
                        },

                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "width" : "150px"
                    }


                ],

                "language": {
                    "emptyTable" : "No data found please click on Add New  Button"
                }

            });
        });

        function PopupForm(url) {

            var formDiv = $('<div />');
            $.get(url)
                .done(function (response) {

                    formDiv.html(response);
                    console.log(response);
                    Popup = formDiv.dialog({

                        autoOpen : true,
                        resizable : false,
                        title : 'Fill Admin Details',
                        height : 450,
                        width : 700,
                        close: function () {

                            Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }

                    });

                });
        }
       

        function SubmitForm(form) {

            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            if ($(form).valid()) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.success) {

                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();

                        $.notify(data.message, {
                            globalPosition: "top center",
                            className:"success"
                        })


                    }
                }
                });
            }

            return false;

        }

    </script>
}
```

In "StoreOrEdit" view part:

```
@model ABC.Models.ADMIN

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("StoreOrEdit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ADMIN_ID)*@

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("ID", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(":", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADMIN_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ID" } })</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADMIN_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Name", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(":", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADMIN_NAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADMIN_NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Pasword", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(":", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADMIN_PASSWORD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADMIN_PASSWORD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Email", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(":", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADMIN_EMAIL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email", @style = "width:580px;" } })</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADMIN_EMAIL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Status", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(":", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADMIN_STATUS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADMIN_STATUS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Comment", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td>@Html.Label(":", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADMIN_COMMENT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>

        </tr>
    </table>


    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-warning" />
    </div>
}
```

In controller parts:

```
//Create Method for Insert and Update
   [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult StoreOrEdit(string adminModel_Id = " ")
        {
            if (adminModel_Id == null)
                return View(new ADMIN());
             
            else
            {

                var query = (from objAdmin in SqlDbContext.ADMINs
                             join objStatus in SqlDbContext.STATUS on objAdmin.ADMIN_STATUS equals objStatus.STATUS_ID
                             select new
                             {
                                 ADMIN_ID = objAdmin.ADMIN_ID,
                                 ADMIN_NAME = objAdmin.ADMIN_NAME,
                                 ADMIN_PASSWORD = objAdmin.ADMIN_PASSWORD,
                                 ADMIN_EMAIL = objAdmin.ADMIN_EMAIL,
                                 STATUS_DESC = objStatus.STATUS_DESC,
                                 ADMIN_COMMENT = objAdmin.ADMIN_COMMENT
                             }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ADMIN_ID == adminModel_Id);
                return View(query);
            }
        }



[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult StoreOrEdit(ADMIN adminModel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (SqlDbContext.ADMINs.Where(x => x.ADMIN_ID.Equals(adminModel.ADMIN_ID)).Count() < 1)
                {
                    ADMIN adminObj = new ADMIN();
                    adminObj.ADMIN_ID = adminModel.ADMIN_ID;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_NAME = adminModel.ADMIN_NAME;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_EMAIL = adminModel.ADMIN_EMAIL;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_STATUS = adminModel.ADMIN_STATUS;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_COMMENT = adminModel.ADMIN_COMMENT;
                    SqlDbContext.ADMINs.Add(adminModel);
                    SqlDbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
                }
                else
                {
                    // db.Entry(adminOb).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    ADMIN adminObj = SqlDbContext.ADMINs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ADMIN_STATUS == "01" && x.ADMIN_ID == adminModel.ADMIN_ID);
                    adminObj.ADMIN_NAME = adminModel.ADMIN_NAME;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_EMAIL = adminModel.ADMIN_EMAIL;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_STATUS = adminModel.ADMIN_STATUS;
                    adminObj.ADMIN_COMMENT = adminModel.ADMIN_COMMENT;
                    SqlDbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated Successfully", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

could someone help me to solve issue please?
Thank you appreciate your help.